# Using accumulate function to sort list (higher order function)

Tags: python

```
def accumulate(fn, initial, seq):
    if seq == ():
        return initial
    else:
        return fn(seq[0], accumulate(fn, initial, seq[1:]))
```

Using `accumulate` I am suppose to write a sorting function.

```
def insertion_sort_hof(tup):
    return accumulate(lambda x,y: x,y = y,x if x > y else None  , () ,tup)
```

This is my code and I don't seem to be able to run it. Why ?

```
insertion_sort_hof(()) # ()
insertion_sort_hof((19,10,1,4,3,1,3, 2))  #(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 10, 19)
```

Comment: How is it not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: `I don't seem to be able to run it.` What do you mean?  Did you call the function?

Comment: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Answer (score 1):

A lambda cannot contain an assignment, so your lambda is invalid. Try adding parentheses like this and you'll get an error message to that effect:

```
lambda x,y: (x,y) = (y,x) if x > y else None
```

And it wouldn't work anyway, since you'd only be swapping the values locally to that function.

Comment: TypeError: unorderable types: int() > tuple() , nope doesn't work

Comment: As I said. Your entire approach is flawed. It needs a rethink.

Comment: @user3398505 The unorderable types error means you are trying to sort data that has no intrinsic order, i.e. what comes first, the number `0` or `['hat', 'balloon']`?  When you see that, you have to ask yourself "what am I trying to do?" because your input data is not uniform.